# Loss of keyboard input in Typescript file (Visual Studio)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, keyboard

Several times a day, I randomly lose the ability to type characters in typescript (.ts) files on Visual Studio 2015.

- I can paste text in successfully
- Semicolon, navigation, enter, delete and backspace keys are still working.
- No other file type have this issue

The only solution so far is to restart Visual Studio.

============== [Update] =======================

I noticed this in the project properties when the issue happens:

[image]

Reloading the project or the solution doesn't help.

Comment: I am having this same problem, but restarting VS and restarting my computer didn't help...

Comment: I am able to modify the ts files when I open VS in safe mode. I tried uninstalling all of my plugins, but I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by removing the `noResolve` option from tsconfig.json and restarting Visual Studio. Here is a link to the bug for this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7367#

Per mhegazy:

> Looks like we were running into an exception looking up a file reference in a dictionary that we did not add previously because of noResolve. I have a fix queued, and should be in the next release.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't make a difference in my case.Whether noResolve is set to true, false, or is missing doesn't fix the loss of keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with VS2015 and reshaper 10.xxx. I suspended re-sharper and that did not work. I then went into the typescript properties for my project and noticed my ECMAScript version drop down was not set to anything. I changed it to ECMAScript 6 and my keyboard came back. Unfortunately I started getting all kinds of red squiggles after that. VS2015 is not quite ready for Angular2 and ECMAScript 6 in my opinion.

Comment: I also ruled out resharper 10 today. I tried to access the Typescript properties for the project when I had the issue again, but received an error. I updated my post with that error.