# In TypeScript files, Keyboard is not responding in VS 2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Lately, I installed VS 2015 with Update 2. I'm not able to edit typescript files (any .ts). the file is responding to Enter, Backspace, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, but i cannot do the simple typing!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6392

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loss of keyboard input in Typescript file (Visual Studio)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36706724/11683)

Comment: thank you all. Before checking these comments I fixed it by doing the steps in this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888115/visual-studio-2015-rtm-lost-javascript-support-after-update-typesript-tools?answertab=active#tab-top